# How to control boost::asio initialisation on Windows?

Tags: boost-asio, winsock, winsock2

I'm developing a program for a system running Windows 7 Embedded.
The program uses `boost::asio` sockets to communicate on both UDP and TCP sockets (it acts as a DHCP server and it's controlled by a RESTful interface).

Normally it works fine. However, occasionally it doesn't initialise correctly and won't respond to any DHCP or HTTP messages. I suspect that this is because the program has started before the underlying `Winsock` is ready. I naively attempted to wait for the `Winsock` to initialise prior to creating the `boost::asio::io_service` and sockets using the code below:

```
WSADATA wsaData;
while (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData))
{
  BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "WSAStartup failed, waiting...";
  boost::this_thread::sleep_for(COMMS_DELAY_PERIOD);
}
```

But I now realise that `boost::asio` is initialised *before* main is called on a Windows system. See the code below from `winsock_init.hpp`:

```
// Static variable to ensure that winsock is initialised before main, and
// therefore before any other threads can get started.
static const winsock_init<>& winsock_init_instance = winsock_init<>(false);
```

Is there a way to ensure that `asio` is correctly initialised in a Windows system before using it, without editing the DLL?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/changeset/84877 or this http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html (the last item for 1.54)

Comment: Thank you @StefanNäwe. However, a comment in 1.54 version of `winsock_init.hpp` states: "With MSVC, this may be accomplished by adding the following code to the DLL..." Do you know how to do it *without* editing the DLL?

Comment: You're the developer and can't change *your* DLL ?

Comment: Ha ha @Stefan very funny. I can't edit *my* DLL, 'cause I don't have one! However, on closer inspection of the comments in `winsock_init.hpp` I realise that I can disable it as shown below.

Answer (score 0):

In now appreciate that the comments about DLLs in `winsock_init.hpp` is just an example, the `asio` library isn't built in to a DLL. 
Also the example code only applies to MSVC (not surprising since it's Windows specific). However, on our project we build with both MSVC and MinGw (gcc) under Qt. The following code worked for us:

```
#include <boost/asio/detail/winsock_init.hpp>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  #pragma warning(push)
  #pragma warning(disable:4073)
  #pragma init_seg(lib)
  boost::asio::detail::winsock_init<>::manual manual_winsock_init;
  #pragma warning(pop)
#else // using MinGw (gcc)
  boost::asio::detail::winsock_init<>::manual manual_winsock_init
    __attribute__ ((init_priority (101)));
#endif
```

Comment: It would be really great if you could share more than a copy and paste from the boost header file. All this does is increment the ref counter in the static data_ member for the winsock_init object, thus bypassing the internal WSAStartup. This in itself isn't a solution.